# Is there a way so that I can make reCaptcha responsive to div

Tags: html, css, flask, recaptcha

Is there a way so that I can make it fit inside and responsive too?

[image: reCaptcha floating out]

[image: Flask sending reCaptcha value]

** UPDATE IN QUESTION ** : I Can't change recaptcha code because my backend validates the recaptcha

Please let me know If I can make changes in side that element,Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer with the possible workout with data-size attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adjust the width of iframe in your CSS even if you can't change the code in HTML.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
  iframe{
  position: relative;
  width:70%;
  left: -69px;
  }
}
```

Comment: That won't make it smaller for a mobile-kind-of-small. There are width and height limits forced by Google. Just saying

Answer (score 4):

Google reCaptcha is generated as an iframe so it has its complete own set of CSS/else libraries and that makes it very hard ~ impossible to edit it because of the Same-domain policy.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

You can set the `data-size` `attribute` to `compact` that could help

```html
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-size="compact"></div>
```

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display

Since you can't modify the HTML source, you can use jQuery to add the `data-size` attribute to the g-recaptcha div. Make sure you load jQuery somewhere using the CDN too. Inspect the page with DevTools, find the div, then target its class or ID using JS and use .attr() to add the attribute to it.

```js
$('.g-recapatcha').attr('data-size','compact');
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but can't edit my reCaptcha HTML because of flask as backend as you can see in updated question

Comment: Don't need jQuery for this, use plain JS:
```js
document.getElementsByClassName("g-recaptcha")[0].setAttribute("data-size", "compact")
```

Comment: Tried both but still no luck if you want the code for reCaptcha i will update it in question just ask thanks for the effort

Answer (score 0):

You should listen [avia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11135092/avia) and use `data-size` attribute: `compact` or `normal`,
I have for my web, DOMContentLoaded on top, which check if screen is smaller as `px`,
then `setAttribute`into div. Check out:

```html
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    
<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    if (window.innerWidth < 476) {
    document.getElementById("recaptcha-div").setAttribute('data-size','compact');
    }else{
    document.getElementById("recaptcha-div").setAttribute('data-size','normal');
    };
    });
    </script>

    <div id="recaptcha-div" class="g-recaptcha" data-theme="dark" data-sitekey="xxxx"></div>
```